# Autofac request lifetime scope always null using Web Api 2.2 integration (3.4)

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I'm using the autofac web api 2.2 integration (version 3.4) and I'm debugging one of my controllers.  It seems like the request lifetime scope is always null when I try the following from any point where I'd expect there to be an active request:

```
var x = (AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver) GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver;
x.GetRequestLifetimeScope();  // always null
```

Is this expected behavior?  I'm a bit confused because it looks like all of my components are resolved at 'root' which, according to the documentation is bad.  I was expecting it to automatically put it into a request scope when I register using InstancePerRequest().  It seems like:

```
AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver.BeginScope()
```

never happens.

I could post more sample code, but I've reproduced it following the quick start guide with very basic controllers, so I suspect it's more of a flaw in my logic above and was hoping someone could point it out.  Thanks!

Comment: could you share your *Autofac* *Web Api* configuration ? See http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html for more information on how to configure *Web API* with *Autofacù

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my issue was that I copied my autofac configuration from a MVC project and was registering my dependencies with `InstancePerRequest`. When I changed that to `InstancePerDependency` instead it solved the problem and `GetRequestLifetimeScope` was working.

```
builder.RegisterType<X>().As<IX>().InstancePerDependency();
```

Answer (score 0):

In action method, you can get the request scope by

```
var scope = Request.GetDependencyScope();
```